# How to reset setInterval function on event click on popup close

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

```
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    setInterval(function () {
                        $.magnificPopup.open({
                            items: {
                                src: '#test-popup'
                            },
                            type: 'inline'
                        });
                    }, <?php echo $time_popup; ?>);
                });
            </script>
```

This is my script. I try to reset set interval function, when click close to popup. I use magnific popup, try with [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp), without result.

Comment: What do you mean by "Even click" ?

Comment: Event click, close on popup window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to assign your `setInterval` call to a variable to be able to reset it with `clearInterval`.

```
var timer = setInterval(function() {
    // Your stuff.
    clearInterval(timer);
});
```

From the [docs you shared](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp):

> The `clearInterval()` method clears a timer set with the `setInterval()` method.
>
> **The ID value returned by `setInterval()` is used as the parameter for the `clearInterval()` method.**

Comment: Ok, but how to call that variable then ? with time interval ?