# Need to call script every second, or better solution?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my script:

```
        <script>
            function getCookie(cname) {
                var name = cname + "=";
                var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
                var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
                for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                    var c = ca[i];
                    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                        c = c.substring(1);
                    }
                    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                        return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
                    }
                }
                return "";
            }

            var time_popup = <?php echo $time_popup; ?>;
            $(document).ready(function () {
                    $.magnificPopup.open({
                        items: {
                            src: '#recently-viewed-popup'
                        },
                        type: 'inline',
                        callbacks: {
                            close: function closePopup() {
                                var close = new Date();
                                close.setMinutes(close.getMinutes() + time_popup);
                                document.cookie = "close_popup=" + close;
                            }
                        }
                    });
            });

            var time_now = new Date();
            var popup_close = getCookie('close_popup');

            if (time_now - time_popup == popup_close) {
                $.magnificPopup.open({
                    items: {
                        src: '#recently-viewed-popup'
                    },
                    type: 'inline',
                    callbacks: {
                        close: function closePopup() {
                            var close = new Date();
                            close.setMinutes(close.getMinutes() + time_popup);
                            document.cookie = "close_popup=" + close;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
```

I have a popup. i have `var time_popup` it comes from admin, he choose minutes to show popup again (After it closed). When popup is closed i setCookie with time now + minutes from admin, when he want to popup again.

The logic is simple:

> Time now - time_popup == last_time_close_popup

**But how to check this every second, the logic is in the last if.**

Comment: You have a low ratio of questions/accepted answers. If you want more people to help you, don't be disgraceful to the people that put effort into helping you and start accepting answers, as is the main reason for this site to live. Btw I'm only seeing one question that have a correct answer. The other questions don't have answers to accept.

Comment: Maybe i found a bug here: "close.setMinutes(close.getMinutes() + time_popup);" i dont need to add time_popup here, i think.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález I think you might need to read his questions, and show a little tolerance. J.Ho has asked good questions showing code and I see no history of dis-respect

Comment: I have 6 question, i have answers on three of them and i have 3 acceptable answers ? 100/100 ?

Comment: @AndyDonegan Yes, I said I only saw one question, that he just accepted an answer (this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45282984/how-to-reset-setinterval-function-on-event-click-on-popup-close). Now is ok. Just keep it that way J. I saw a lot of users starting to not accept answers and when they reach 20 questions, they have 10 without accepting answers. I usually post this kind comments and OPs start to accept answers, like this time, and then advice to keep it up that way :P

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález I totally agree with your sentiment and reasoning, it is solid advice. Lets leave this one for J.Ho to get his answer now :)

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález Comments were deleted so can't really tell what was said, but I can tell you from my experiences, I've had very good questions with people trolling or something but just being really rude. I was rude back. Not saying you were or weren't, but sometimes people on here can be a little much. I've learned and try not to respond to rude people anymore, but sometimes enough is enough.

Comment: @J.Ho Take a lok at jonathongoodman's answer. This is what you want. Essentially it will wait until that time is up (so you don't have to do what you're trying to) can call whatever's inside it after the time elapsed. It's in milliseconds too, so let's say `3000` would be 3 seconds. You can calculate based on the time difference to know how many milliseconds to use.

Comment: Thanks for attention, i tried with setTimeout(), but without success.

Comment: @J.Ho What have you tried with `setTimeout`? Can you share a fiddle? Actually is how it has to be done. EDIT: Oh, I saw your reply with the setInterval. Let's see if someone helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could use JavaScripts `setTimeout()` method

That way you don't need to check every second to see if 5 minutes has past. Set timeout will run the function you pass to its first argument after the time in milliseconds passed in to its second argument.

```
setTimeout(function(){
  // logic
}, 300000);
```

Comment: This is the only real answer.

Answer (score 0):

Finally it's done with one small bug, if someone can help me. This is solution:

```
    </style>
    <?php if ($popup_status && !empty($products)) { ?>
        <script>
            var time_popup = <?php echo $time_popup; ?>;
            var route = '<?php echo $route; ?>';
            $(document).ready(function () {
                if ((sessionStorage.getItem('popState') != 'shown') && (route == 'common/home' || route == 'index')) {
                    sessionStorage.setItem('popState', 'shown')
                    $.magnificPopup.open({
                        items: {
                            src: '#recently-viewed-popup'
                        },
                        type: 'inline',
                        callbacks: {
                            close: function closePopup() {
                                var close = new Date();
                                $.cookie("close_popup", close);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            setInterval(function () {
                var time_now = new Date();
                var popup_close = $.cookie('close_popup');
                time_now.setMinutes(time_now.getMinutes() - time_popup)
                console.log(time_now);
                console.log(popup_close);
                if (time_now == popup_close) {
                    $.magnificPopup.open({
                        items: {
                            src: '#recently-viewed-popup'
                        },
                        type: 'inline',
                        callbacks: {
                            close: function closePopup() {
                                var close = new Date();
                                $.cookie("close_popup", close);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }, 1000);
        </script>
```

But now when popup is open and it's not closed yet and page reloaded popup never open again.